# Why is "witcher" not translated in the Italian dub of the Netflix series?

Tags: translation, dubbing, the-witcher

In the Italian translations of Sapkowski's novels, "witcher" is translated as [*strigo*](https://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strega).<sup>1</sup> However, the Italian dub of the Netflix series (and the video games) use the English word *witcher*.<sup>2</sup>

Why is this?

Is it to avoid confusion with the cognate [*strige*](https://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strige) (a monster which also appears in the series)?

---

<sup>1. A pseudo-romance word for "male witch", based on *strega* ("witch") as opposed to the more usual *stregone* ("warlock, sorcerer") or *mago* ("mage").</sup>

<sup>2. in the Spanish and French dubs, he is known as *brujo* and *sorceleur* respectively.</sup>

Comment: Witcher was called "Wiedźmin" in original polish language. Before the games were released, the books were using the English translation "Hexer", only after the games, "Witcher" came into use. The ownership of the "Witcher" trademark belongs to the company that made the game. Previously it was unsure if Netflix would even be able to use this word. So maybe in italian Strigo is also owned by someone and could be used? If not, than probably Witcher was used for marketing purposes - to make people connect the show to the games.

Comment: Is the show named Il Strigo on Netflix in Italy? If not, there is your answer.

Comment: @RigaCrypto the show is named *The WItcher* in Spanish, but nonetheless witchers are referred to as *brujos* within show dialogue.

Comment: @ukemi Ok, strange. Usually if a show has a generic name in it, dubs either translate the title also, or stick with the original denomination as to not confuse the viewer. Then I don't know why they didn't translate it.